# Searchbar in Ionic is not working

Tags: typescript, ionic3, searchbar

I am trying the search in Ionic but it shows the error at the bottom.
First, I retrieve some data from API and I want to filter in that results.

The following is my html, it shows the retrieving of data and also a searchbar

```
<ion-header>

 <ion-navbar color="toolcolor">
<ion-title>Doctor Appointments</ion-title>
<!--<ion-buttons color="toolcolor" end><button id="search" 
(click)="search()"><ion-icon name="search" color="light"></ion-icon></button> 
</ion-buttons> -->
 <ion-searchbar [(ngModel)]="ev" (ionInput)="getItems($ev)"></ion-searchbar>
 </ion-navbar>

 </ion-header>


    <ion-content padding> 

     <div class="card">
     <ion-item color="toolcolor">

     <ion-label color="light">Select Date</ion-label>
     <ion-datetime   displayFormat="MMM DD YYYY" [(ngModel)]="event.month" > 
    </ion-datetime>
    </ion-item>
    <br>
    <div *ngFor="let item of items">
    <button class="doc_appoint" (click)="patientdetails()">
     <ion-label id="pat_det">Time:{{ item.time }}</ion-label>
     <ion-label id="pat_det">Patient Name:</ion-label>
     <ion-label id="pat_det">Patient ID:{{ item.PatientId }}</ion-label>
    </button>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br>
    </div>
   </div>



   </ion-content>
```

My ts, it shows the searchbar function
I don't know where I made the mistake

```
 getItems(ev) {
   this.show();
   var val = ev.target.value;
    if (val && val.trim() != '') {
    this.items = (this.items).filter((item) => {

    return ((item.PatientId).toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
    })
    }
    }
```

and my error
[image]

I don't know how to overcome this.
Any suggestions are welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your `getItems` method `ev` seems to be undefined. Make sure you don't override it somewhere in your code. Maybe also try to remove `[(ngModel)]="ev"` to prevent a variable collision...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `[(ngModel)]="ev"`, delete it.

In the function `getItems` change the signature from `getItems(ev)` to `getItems(ev: any)`.